# libsox: record from default microphone

Tags: c, cross-platform, libsox

I need to open the default audio capture device and start recording. `libsox` seems to be [a nice cross-platform solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435233/capturing-audio-input-from-microphone-with-haskell). Using the binary frontend, I can just `rec test.wav` and the default microphone is activated.

However, when browsing the [documentation](http://sox.sourceforge.net/libsox.pdf), no similar functionality exists. [This thread](http://sox.10957.n7.nabble.com/Recording-from-Microphone-td5460.html) discusses precisely the same topic as my question, but doesn't seem to have reached a solution.

Where could an example of using `libsox` for recording from the default audio device be located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can record using libsox. Just set the input file to "default" and set the filetype to the audio driver (e.g. coreaudio on mac, alsa or oss on linux)

```
const char* audio_driver = "alsa";
sox_format_t* input = sox_open_read("default", NULL, NULL, audio_driver);
```

Look at some [examples](https://github.com/dmkrepo/libsox/blob/master/src/example0.c) for more info on how to structure the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to record with alsa first and use libsox for the right format. libsox is not for recording. see example: https://gist.github.com/albanpeignier/104902

Comment: This defeats the purpose of being cross-platform, then.

Comment: so why not using https://github.com/andrewrk/libsoundio ? also searching on google may find some more. libsox is "...is a library of sound sample file format readers/writers and sound effects processors."