# How can I stream microphone data into my Haskell program?

Tags: haskell, sdl, microphone

I would like to create some instrument-tuning software, doing the frequency analysis in Haskell.

I could perhaps do this by analyzing recorded audio files, but would like to stream the audio from a microphone into the program in real-time.

How might I do this? I noticed [SDL](https://wiki.haskell.org/SDL) which, being a "hardware abstraction layer" looked promising, but am interested in all suggestions.

Comment: Have SO's 'off-topic' standards changed recently? Notice this duplicate question from a few years ago that has gathered useful feedback and interaction. Fortunately answers to it were permitted and answer this duplicate question, so it's lucky that question was not immediately closed as this duplicate has been.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435233/capturing-audio-input-from-microphone-with-haskell
@DanielWagner

Comment: My bigger concern with your question is that you have shown no significant research effort. But since you apparently feel that your own question is a duplicate, please just delete it.

Comment: @skomisa the question demonstrates prior research by suggesting a possible answer, asking about it, and linking to it. 'Deleting' is not what we do with duplicate questions on stackoverflow -- we mark them as duplicates.

Comment: But presumably you would not have even created this question in the first place if you had seen the duplicate before posting rather than after, right? Since the question has been closed for other reasons and can't be marked as a duplicate I don't see how keeping this question is useful. (To be clear I don't mean that rudely at all - I'm only mean it in the context of SO rules on questions)

Comment: @skomisa I'm trying to follow SO's policy for duplicate questions. Do you think the linked question I found is in fact a duplicate? If so, then presumably you don't think *this* question should have been closed as 'off-topic' either -- so vote to re-open it. If it is reopened, then it can be marked as a duplicate per SO's policy.

Comment: Point taken. I have voted to reopen based on your suggestion, but to be clear, I think the linked duplicate should be closed because _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"_. That said, closing this question as a duplicate of that one seems the least bad option.